# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle - Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use configuration like documentation. This is my security file:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        provider: fos_userbundle
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
            - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

access_control:
- { path: ^/api/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and my routing file

```
api_login_check:
     path: /api/login_check
```

When I get in m browser to /api/login_check i get error

> Unable to find the controller for path "/api/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

change your security.yml login firewall configuration with the following:

```
login:
    pattern:  ^/api/login
    stateless: true
    anonymous: true
    form_login:
        check_path:               /api/login_check
        success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

remove login_check path from your access control it should be already configured

```
- { path: ^/api/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: You have set the check_path within form_login when it should be json_login

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your access control configuration :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I am pretty sure you use API Platform for this, if you [read the documentation here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt#installing-lexikjwtauthenticationbundle), you will see that the access control on the login URL use `^/login` in the `path` and not `^/api/login_check`

Comment: So i should implement login controller? And m endpoint get /login not /login_check?